# Get precise decimal string representation of Python Decimal?

Tags: python, decimal

If I've got a Python `Decimal`, how can I reliably get the precise decimal string (ie, not scientific notation) representation of the number without trailing zeros?

For example, if I have:

```
>>> d = Decimal('1e-14')
```

I would like:

```
>>> get_decimal_string(d)
'0.00000000000001'
```

However:

1. The `Decimal` class doesn't have any `to_decimal_string` method, or even any `to_radix_string(radix)` (cf: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.to_eng_string)
2. The `%f` formatter either defaults to rounding to 6 decimal places - `'%f' %(d, ) ==> '0.000000'` - or requires a precise number of decimal places.
3. The `{:f}.format(...)` formatter *appears* to work - `'{:f}'.format(d)
   ==> '0.00000000000001'` - *however* I'm reluctant to trust that, as this actually runs counter to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#index-9), which says "`'f'` … Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6"
4. `Decimal.__repr__` and `Decimal.__str__` sometimes return scientific notation: `repr(d) ==> "Decimal('1E-14')"`

So, is there any way to get a decimal string from a Python `Decimal`? Or do I need to roll my own using `Decimal.as_tuple()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
>>> d
Decimal('1E-14')
>>> '{:f}'.format(d)
'0.00000000000001'
```

#### Long answer:

As [Brandon Rhodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85360/brandon-rhodes) pointed out [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-specifiers) (which is the string format PEP) states:

> The syntax for format specifiers is open-ended, since a class can
>   override the standard format specifiers. In such cases, the
>   str.format() method merely passes all of the characters between the
>   first colon and the matching brace to the relevant underlying
>   formatting method.

And thus, the `Decimal.__format__` method is what python's string format will utilize to generate the `str` representation of the `Decimal` value.  Basically `Decimal` overrides the formatting to be "smart" but will default to whatever values the format string sets (ie `{:.4f}` will truncate the decimal to 4 places).

Here's why you can trust it (snippet from `decimal.py:Decimal.__format__`):

```py
def __format__(self, specifier, context=None, _localeconv=None):
    #
    # ...implementation snipped.
    #

    # figure out placement of the decimal point
    leftdigits = self._exp + len(self._int)
    if spec['type'] in 'eE':
        if not self and precision is not None:
            dotplace = 1 - precision
        else:
            dotplace = 1
    elif spec['type'] in 'fF%':
        dotplace = leftdigits
    elif spec['type'] in 'gG':
        if self._exp <= 0 and leftdigits > -6:
            dotplace = leftdigits
        else:
            dotplace = 1

    # find digits before and after decimal point, and get exponent
    if dotplace < 0:
        intpart = '0'
        fracpart = '0'*(-dotplace) + self._int
    elif dotplace > len(self._int):
        intpart = self._int + '0'*(dotplace-len(self._int))
        fracpart = ''
    else:
        intpart = self._int[:dotplace] or '0'
        fracpart = self._int[dotplace:]
    exp = leftdigits-dotplace

    # done with the decimal-specific stuff;  hand over the rest
    # of the formatting to the _format_number function
    return _format_number(self._sign, intpart, fracpart, exp, spec)
```

Long story short, the `Decimal.__format__` method will calculate the necessary padding to represent the number before and after the decimal based upon exponentiation provided from `Decimal._exp` (in your example, 14 significant digits).

```
>>> d._exp
-14
```

Comment: The documentation you quoted only deals with the internal representation, not what `format` is going to produce.

Comment: Right, which is why I said it wasn't clear.  It only implies through the examples that the formatting will work as expected.  There is no explicit discussion of interaction with string's .format method.  I will continue looking, and post if I find anything.  Another interesting part of those docs:  "Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem:" but this value doesn't seem to affect the string formatting.

Comment: See my point 3, above: this _appears_ to work, but it contradicts what the `string.format` documentation says about the behavior of `'f'`, so I'm reluctant to trust it.

Comment: When in doubt: use the source, haha.  I'll update the answer, but basically you can trust it because of the `Decimal.__format__` methods implementation.

Comment: I recommend checking out the source code for decimal.py, as the formatting is very unique.  It's a shame none of that is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Remember that `string.format` has no control over what format operators actually do any more — it's now deferred to `__format__()` methods.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes great point, which makes me even more confident that this is the right answer.