# Check if Python Decimal ends with a certain value

Tags: python, decimal

I have a bunch of Decimal objects. I want to test each one to see if it ends in `.43`. I can do this by first converting it to a string:

```
>>> num = Decimal('1.43')
>>> str(num).endswith('.43')
True
```

But that fails if I don't know what precision the Decimal was created with.

```
>>> num = Decimal('1.4300')
>>> str(num).endswith('.43')
False
```

I could do the string conversion and check if it contains `.43`.

```
>>> num = Decimal('1.4300')
>>> '.43' in str(num)
True
```

But that also matches other values, which I don't want.

```
>>> num = Decimal('1.4321')
>>> '.43' in str(num)
True
```

How can I check if the decimal ends in `.43`, with any number of trailing zeroes?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/54013614/5320906

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be best to use mathematical reasoning here, avoiding the float domain (inaccurate) and the string domain (unnecessary).  If you subtract `0.43` from a number ending in `.43`, you should be left with an integer, and you can check that using modulo operator `%`:

```
>>> point43 = Decimal("0.43") 
>>> num = Decimal('1.43') 
>>> (abs(num) - point43) % 1 == 0 
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the modulus operator like this:

(The modulus operator here strips the integer value. `32.48%1` turns into `0.48`. The absolute value function makes it positive. `abs(-32.48)` will turn into `32.48`. Thanks @wim.)

```
>>> num = float('1.4300')       # changes input into float (removes trailing 0s automatically)
>>> round(abs(num)%1, 2) == .43 # checks if it ends with .43 with 2 decimal points
True
```

Comment: True. I shall go fix that.

Comment: ... I guess your's uses his custom Decimal class where mine just says no to it. Uh...

Comment: I tried the modulus operator in python 3 and for 1.340 it returns 0.3400000001 and so when comparing with 0.34 it fails. You know why?

Comment: I'd hesitate to call this "correct"; comparing two `float`s for equality is sensitive to rounding error. @wim's answer ensures that all operations continue to be done on `Decimal` values.

Comment: I think my answer is susceptible to rounding point errors. I'll round it again then :|

Comment: @GeeTransit That's not the only problem; you can't assume that the float literal `0.43` is accurate in the first place. Look at the result of `Decimal(0.43)` compared to `Decimal("0.43")` to see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to a string then strip off the trailing 0s before checking as follows.

```
num = Decimal('1.4300')
print(str(num).rstrip('0').endswith('.43'))
#Prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could strip your string of zeros

```
>>> num = Decimal('1.4300')
>>> str(num).strip('0').endswith('.43')
True
```